# How to decode the event logs in polygonscan mumbai?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript, evm

This is my transaction hash: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x79ed502a8d319ab3b278781042898115d9d6bece15d3d91626a7a6a39c0873b3#eventlog  The event logs of the event DataCredentialized is not human readable. I am not sure how to decode these logs. It would be helpful if someone could help me with a javascript code to decode these logs. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you cannot decode these logs. The hex values are hashed with the `keccak256` function which makes it *nearly* impossible to get the original values. 
In your case you have two indexed topics:

1. 0xa73d61b387464bf2a657f753d27d72552be88c48d7b0e3adc6a3413fb0b01e2d
2. 0x93896ac593a0be8d1921c503fdc75208d8b9d573d83b479b03916c5a6b5781db

Where the 1. value was hashed in the contract with `keccak256` 
The 2. value is also a Keccak-256 hash. Since you wanted to emit a reference type (memory string). You can read more [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.20/contracts.html#events) about Events.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction you linked emits the event *DataCredentialized*:

```
event DataCredentialized(bytes32 indexed viewToken, string indexed ipfsUrl);
```

Taking a closer look at the contract, you will find a viewer function called  `viewCredentializedData()` that allows you to decode the data by passing the argument retrieved from the event log.

Comment: at left of of `Topics 1` choose `Hex` then copy that data and paste in. `https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xc47d9b99fcf7c3d71630f6987a29002183902e43#readContract` at `viewCredentializedData` first argument then `Query`